# Calculate Duration based on date and events

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a DF and I want to calculate the time between earnings dates.

DF

```
Date          Earnings Reported           
2018-04-02    1          
2018-04-03    0
2018-04-04    0
```

DF - Desired

```
Date          Earnings Reported       DaySinceEarnings      
2018-04-02    1                       0
2018-04-03    0                       1
2018-04-04    0                       2
```

I tried to do a lambda function but couldn't get it working

```
df['DaySinceEarnings'] = df.groupby['Earnings Reported'].apply(lambda x: (x == '1') * (x == '1').cumsum())
```

Comment: df.Date.diff().dt.days.cumsum() ?

Comment: how would that even work?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': ['2018-04-02',
              '2018-04-03',
              '2018-04-04',
              '2018-04-05',
              '2018-04-06',
              '2018-04-07', ],
     'Earnings Reported': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]}
)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


def only_include_reported_days(x):
    x['DaySinceEarnings'] = 0
    if x['Earnings Reported'] == 1:
        return x

    sub = df[(df['Date'] < x['Date']) &
             (df['Earnings Reported'] == 1)]

    x['DaySinceEarnings'] = (x['Date'] - max(sub['Date'])).days
    return x
```

Comment: hey kaitlyn, I tired the above code.  DaySinceEarnings = is missing x2 values after the groupby line of code.   Then after the lambda apply it is missing x3 values for daysinceearnings